# Many method argument vs a bulk argument

Tags: php, laravel, performance

In terms of efficiency which one is better :

1. Method with many arguments
2. A bulk argument that contains all of mentioned arguments

I mean :

```
public function addToDb($firstName, $lastName, $phone, $address, ...)
{
```

Or

```
public function addToDb(Request $request)
{
  $firstName = $request->firstName;
  $lastName= $request->lastName;
  $phone= $request->phone;
  $address= $request->address;
  //
```

Please keep in mind that in this example `$request` class maybe has many useless arguments and methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second method is more priority. For example you define

```
function addToDb($firstName, $lastName, $phone, $address){...}
```

And used this methods for example 10 times. If in the future your app need some changes and you must be change some parameter for example `$firstName, $lastName,` must be change to `name`, that case you must be change your initial function to

```
function addToDb($name, $phone, $address){...}
```

And int 10 times where called this methods you also must be change. But in seconds Case you must be change only body of function like this

```
public function addToDb(Request $request)
{
  $name = $request->firstName . '' . $request->lastName;
```

Also you can use 3-rd structure

```
function someFunction(...) {
    $parameterWithData = [
        'firstName' => 'firt name',
        'lastName' => 'last name'
        .....
    ];
    $this->test($parameterWithData);
}


function test($parameterWithData)
{
    extract($parameterWithData);
    dd($firstName, $lastName); // must be print `first_name, last name`
}
```

in `extract` function all keys you can use as `variable` http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: It does not matter, for example,$request has 1000 unused attribute and this does not decrease the performance??

Answer (score 4):

The main rule is "The ideal number of arguments for a function is
zero". Of course it hard to do that but we should keep code simply and better is the second solutions, especially when you use Data Value Object